# How to close modal window with clicking on background with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a modal window and already relies 2 ways of closing (with click on button and with press on esc key)
now I want to add last one it is a click on background, outside of main popup content window

I've found similar question with this issue, but I didn't get solution yet.

HTML

```
<div class="popup popup_menu">
<div class="popup_wrapper" >
<div class="popup_inner">
<div class="popup_container" >
<button class="btn_close popup_btn_close"></button>
<nav class="mobile_menu">
<ul class="mobile_menu_ul">
<li class="mobile_menu_li"><a href="" class="mobile_menu_link">Суші</a></li>
<li class="mobile_menu_li"><a href="" class="mobile_menu_link">Про нас</a></li>
<li class="mobile_menu_li"><a href="" class="mobile_menu_link">Контакти</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div class="mobile_phone">
<a class="phone_item mobile_phone_item" href="tel:+30505555555">+3 (050) 555-55-55</a>
</div>
<ul class="socials_items">
<li class="socials_link"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="/img/facebook.png" alt=""></a></li>
<li class="socials_link"><a href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><img src="/img/instagram.png" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
let showPopup = document.querySelector('.btn_menu');
let closePopup = document.querySelector('.btn_close');
let body = document.querySelector('body');

showPopup.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.popup_menu').classList.add('popup_active');
  document.querySelector('body').classList.add('no_scroll');
});
closePopup.addEventListener('click', function close() {
  document.querySelector('.popup_menu').classList.remove('popup_active');
  document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('no_scroll');
});

body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.keyCode !== 27){
    return;
  }
  let popup = document.querySelector('.popup.popup_active');
  if (popup){
    document.querySelector('.popup_menu').classList.remove('popup_active');
    document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('no_scroll');
  }
})
```

Comment: Your code is not complete for example `btn_menu` doesn't exist in your example.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thx, but .btn_menu is not a part of popup, it is a button which call popup

Comment: You need to create a full working snippet with your problem.

Comment: could you create an invisible element sitting over the screen behind your popup and when you click off the element (onto the invisible element) it triggers closing the popup and invisible overlay?